# XSL:Choose query

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I've the code as shown below which gives Stylesheet Compilation error.

```
<xsl:template match="form">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each select="@*">
                <xsl:variable name="param" select="name(.)" />
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$param = 'name'">
                        <xsl:attribute name="name"><xsl:value-of
                            select="@name" /></xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="$param = 'action'">
                        <xsl:attribute name="action"><xsl:value-of
                            select="java:com.hp.cpp.proxy.util.URLUtils.rewriteAction($response, $baseurl, @action, $scope)" /></xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="$param = 'method'">
                        <xsl:attribute name="method">POST</xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:attribute name="$param"><xsl:value-of
                            select="." /></xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <input type="hidden" name="httpmethod">
                <xsl:attribute name="value"> <xsl:value-of
                    select="@method" /></xsl:attribute>
            </input>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />

        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

I'm trying to re-write FORM tag of HTML with quite complex requirement. Hope you'll be able to identify by the code-snap. I'm trying to re-write only few of the attributes of the tag and trying to retain the rest. Is it the right way? Any other way to do it? Any suggestion.

Thanks in advance.

-Rikin

Comment: You say you get a compilation error, but not which one. Also you tag your question as both 1.0 and 2.0, which is it? Can you update your question with a minimal complete example (incl. the xsl:stylesheet and the declared namespaces)? My guess is that the extension method `rewriteAction` is not declared or non-existent.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess. Try to replace the last apply

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
```

by this

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

About the compilation error, you don't provide enough information to help; Abel's conjecture that the compilation error has to do with your call to an extension function is plausible.

You also ask *Is this the right way?* to achieve your goal.  Maybe.  Your first problem here is the logic error that jvverde has already pointed to.  The call to apply templates should not select attributes; you have already dealt with all the attributes. So it's unnecessary to process them again.  It's also a bad idea: if you you try to handle the `form` element's attributes again, you'll get a run-time error because you've already written content to the element (namely that `input` element).

I think some XSLT programmers would write something that looks more like this:

```
<xsl:template match="form">
  <xsl:copy>

    <!--* don't use a for-each to handle the
        * attributes; use templates. *-->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>

    <!--* you don't need an xsl:attribute constructor
        * if you want to use an expression within a 
        * literal result element; just braces in the
        * attribute-value template.
        *-->
    <input type="hidden" 
           name="httpmethod"
           value="{@method}" />

    <!--* change your apply-templates call to
        * select children, but not attributes.
        *-->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!--* now the attributes ... *-->
<xsl:template match="form/@action">
  <xsl:attribute name="action">
    <xsl:value-of select="java:com.hp.cpp.proxy.util.URLUtils.rewriteAction(
                          $response, $baseurl, @action, $scope)" />
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="form/@method">
  <xsl:attribute name="method">
    <xsl:value-of select="'POST'"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```